# Searching upper and lowercase Google Docs scripts

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

Im trying to make a Google Docs script which replaces certain lines of code from languages i use and converts them to the pseudo code we are using. An example of what im trying to do is below

```
body.replaceText("print","OUTPUT");
```

I am new to regex but I want to know if there is a way it will search for `print` regardless of its case for example it will also except `PRINT` and `Print`

I have seen some people converting it to lowercase and then searching but I do not want to do this as this will effect my code and make all text lowercase etc. Is there something I can do so it finds it regardless of case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[p,P][r,R][i,I][n,N][t,T]
```

Here is test:

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wL3uN0/1)

Comment: I'll try it out later but I will probably need to make a programme to convert words into that format as it's alot of typing

Comment: Almost every editor has replace feature, this will help you from extensive typing.

Comment: True but I just finished a small script to automatically type that out and save it all to a .txt to make it quicker